# general solution using undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to get a general solution for a problem I thought of ,using undetermined coefficients.

$y''+y' = xe^x$.  I tried taking initial guess as $ x(Ax+B)e^x$, but this is not working. the extra $x$ in the guess is due to the fact that a constant is present in the complementary solution. So I need help with the general initial guesses when complementary solution contains a constant. what should be my initial guess if function in RHS was $xe^{-x}$?

Comment: The general rule is that your function is a linear polynomial times an exponential. So you need $(Ax+B)e^x$. Then you need to check if any part of this solves the homogeneous ODE. If so, you have to multiply by $x$ until no part of your particular solution solves the homogeneous ODE.

Answer (score 0):

try to guess $$y_p=
\left(Ax+B\right)e^x$$
if you want to know how to complete it say in a comment and ill sent a complete way

the best way i can give you is simply to remember. Ofc you cant remember any single case you will have so you have more thing to remember to not being have to remember  a lot!!(just keep reading...)

---

you have the basic stuff like: $x^n, e^x, \sin(x)$ and then you have combination of them, like: $x^n+2e^x, \sin(x)e^x$.

for the basic stuff i cant help you, you will have to remember. for the "complicated" stuff there are ways you need to remember(note: in all the examples i am giving $g_i(x)$ is a basic function,a function you know what to guess for it)
:$$\text{for: }y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y = g_1(x) + g_2(x) + \cdots + g_n(x)$$
you are dividing it to $n$ equations:$$y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y =g_1(x)\\y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y =g_2(x)\\.\\.\\.\\y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y =g_n(x)$$
you then solve for each one of those and find $y_{p_i}$ and then the final result is $y_p=y_{p_1}+y_{p_2}+\cdots+y_{p_n}$

$$\text{for: }y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y = g_1(x)\times g_2(x)\times\cdots\times g_n(x)$$
this one is a little trickier to explain. i have no way of showing it without an example so after ill try my best to explain ill give an simple an example:

first of all let's call $G_i(x)$ the guess for $g_i(x)$ BUT instead of using variables you are using only $1$. now for $g(x)=g_1(x)\times g_2(x)\times\cdots\times g_n(x)$ you have $G(x)=G_1(x)\times G_2(x)\times\cdots\times G_n(x)$.

now take $G(x)$ and open the brackets. you open the brackets and THEN put a variable before each term.

an example:$$y'' - p(x)y' - q(x)y = x^2\cos(x)\\g(x)=g_1(x)g_2(x), g_1(x)=x^2, g_2=\cos(x)\\G(x)=G_1(x)G_2(x), G_1(x)=x^2+x+1, G_2=\cos(x)+\sin(x)\\G(x)=\left(x^2+x+1\right)(\cos(x)+\sin(x))\\=x^2\cos(x)+x^2\sin(x)+x\cos(x)+x\sin(x)+\cos(x)+\sin(x)$$
therefore the guess is: $Ax^2\cos(x)+Bx^2\sin(x)+Cx\cos(x)+Dx\sin(x)+E\cos(x)+F\sin(x)$

This is the general stuff I know, if you have farther questions ask, maybe I just forgot to put it and I can answer those questions. my guess about the example you gave in the comments is that the partial solution solved the homogeneous ODE so it was multiplied by $x$

Comment: Thank you. is there a general approach? I learnt that if a factor of the given function was part of complementary solution I had to multiply x, but I dont see that happening, since a constant exists in $xe^x$, $1$. and if the function had been just$x$, the guess would have been $Ax^2+Bx$. I saw in another question that if function was $xe^{-x}$, the guess would have been $(Ax^2+Bx)e^{-x}$

Comment: i'll add in the answer what i know. but i have to say that i'm not sure why the guess for $xe^{-x}$ is what you said and not $(Ax+B)e^{-x}$. i never had question with $^{-x}$ so im probably missing something. anywho, ill add info about how to take a guess to the answer

Comment: @jnyan I added what I know to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The partial solution of the equation
$$
y^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\ldots+a_1y'+a_0y=P_n(x)e^{\alpha x},
$$
where $P_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, has the form 
$$
x^m Q_n(x)e^{\alpha x},
$$
where $Q_n(x)$ is a polynomial of the same degree as $P_n(x)$ with undetermined coefficients and $m$ is

- equal to $0$ if $\alpha$ is not a root of the auxillary equation
  $$
  \lambda^{n}+a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1\lambda+a_0=0;
  $$
- equal to the multiplicity of $\alpha$ otherwise.

In this case the auxillary equation 
$$
\lambda^2+\lambda=0
$$
has the roots $0,-1$; $\alpha=1$ is not a root of this equation, thus the partial solution has the form
$$
(Ax+B)e^{x}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

First it is important to look at the characteristic equation. $r^2+r=0$ in this case. which gives roots $r=0,-1$. So the complementary solution is $y_c=c_1+c_2e^{-x}$. Now you can take a "guess" for the particular solution. the RHS is $xe^x$. So for the $x$  we would guess a polynomial of the same degree, i.e. $Ax+B$. For the $e^x$ you guess a multiple of it, i.e. Ce^x. So our initial guess is $y_p=(Ax+B)Ce^x$. Simplify the constants, $y_p=(Dx+E)e^x$. Now the particular solution and the complementary solution should be independent. So if there is a term that is in both, then it is not independent. So compare $y_c=c_1+c_2e^{-x}$ to $y_p=(Dx+E)e^x$. No terms are the same, so our initial guess is the correct one!

Now what if we had $xe^{-x}$ instead. Our $y_c$ is the same, we look at the initial guess. Again, our initial guess for the $x$ is the same, and our guess for the $e^{-x}$ should be $Fe^{-x}$. So our initial guess is $y_p=(Dx+E)e^{-x}$. Now we compare it to $y_c$, keeping in mind that no similar term should be in both. So $y_c=c_1+c_2e^{-x}$ to $y_p=(Dx+E)e^{-x}= Dxe^{-x}+Ee^{-x}$. But the the $Ee^{-x}$ term is similar to the $c_2e^{-x}$ term. So to make sure they are independent we multiple $y_p$ by $x$. Which gives $y_p=(Dx^2+Ex)e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Trying $y=xe^x$, you have

$$(xe^x)''+(xe^x)'=2xe^x+3e^x,$$ which brings you closer to the solution. You need to get rid of the extra $e^x$ term, for which obviously $y=e^x$ is relevant as

$$(e^x)''+(e^x)'=2e^x.$$

Now it suffices to form a suitable linear combination,

$$y=\frac{xe^x}2-\frac{3e^x}4,$$

because

$$\frac12(2xe^x+3e^x)-\frac34(2e^x)=xe^x.$$

Answer (score 0):

The RHS is a polynomial times an exponential. You can observe that the derivative of such a function is also a polynomial times an exponential,

$$(p(x)e^x)'=(p(x)+p'(x))e^x.$$

Also notice that the new polynomial is of the same degree.

Then you should look for a solution in this form. Now,

$$(p(x)e^x)''+(p(x)e^x)'=(p''(x)+3p'(x)+2p(x))e^x=xe^x$$

and you get a simpler equation

$$p''(x)+3p'(x)+2p(x)=x$$ where $P$ is a first degree polynomial, let $p(x)=ax+b$. This yields

$$3a+2(ax+b)=x$$ or

$$p(x)=\frac x2-\frac34.$$